# How do I perform an index-based transform in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, transform

let's say I have a matrix `M` that has a size of `1024`.  Let's say I use meshgrid to get the following x and y indexes.

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:1024, 1:1024);
```

Next, let's apply some function to `x` and `y` (e.g. with the goal of producing a fisheye or pincushion effect).

```
x_new = func1(x);
y_new = func2(y);
```

Now using these matrices for the transformed `x` and `y` coordinates, `x_new` and `y_new`, how do I create a new matrix `N` with these transformed index mappings?  In other words, is there a more elegant way of doing the following?

```
for i = 1:1024
    for j = 1:1024
        N(i, j) = M(x_new(i, j), y_new(i, j));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to approach this problem turns out to be transforming subscripted indices in the form of (i, j) into linear indices.  This operation produces a 1024x1024 matrix, which is tractable.  We can do the following:

```
linIndices = sub2ind(size(x_new), x_new, y_new));
N = M(linIndices);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 N=reshape(diag(M(x_new,y_new)),[N,N])
```

By calling `M(x_new,y_nex)` you get N^2 by N^2 matrix with all possible indices combinations. You need only the main diagonal of this matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately this creates too large for an array in my case.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than applying a function to the row/column index values and then trying to use them to index back into `M`, why not just use `interp2` to sample `M` at your new locations? This allows you to have non-integer values returned from `func1` and `func2`.

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:1024, 1:1024);
N = interp2(x, y, M, func1(x), func2(y));
```